# Postman Client Requests to TFS

Tags: tfs, postman, devops

Can I use the Postman client to send web requests to our on premise TFS endpoint URIs? I have a personal access token. What type of auth should I be using? I keep getting a TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.

I am passing in the token using OAuth 1.0

Comment: Did you refer to the REST API documentation? Specifically, the section on authenticating with a PAT.

Comment: @DanielMann  Yes I did. Thank you.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Choose **Basic Auth**, and fill the PAT in Password field. For Username field, you can type anything.

***Notice***: you have to **disable** IIS Basic Authentication, then PAT can work. Check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/get-started/authentication/iis-basic-auth